# Python Threads Run When Created, Not When run() is Called

Tags: python-2.7, python-multithreading

In my python program (2.7), I attempt to create a thread but it instantly starts when it is created, not when the start() and then the run() attributes are called. Help would be great.

Here is my (server) code:

```
import sys
import socket
import threading
global connections
connections = []

def srcv(s, conn, data):

    while True:

        print "Recieving"
        #Recieve Strings From Each Connection
        for i, n in enumerate(connections):

            data.append([connections[1], i.recv(4096)])

        #Send String To Each Connection
        print "Sending"
        for i, n in enumerate(connections):

            i.send("{0}: {1}".format(data[n][0], data[n][1]))

def listn(s, conn, data):

    s.listen(10)
    print "Listening For Connection"
    while True:

        obj, addr = s.accept()
        connections.append([obj, addr])

def start_server():

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    conn = []
    data = []
    s.bind(("localhost", 12345))
     print "Creating Listening Thread"
    listen = threading.Thread(target=listn(s,conn,data))
    print "Preparing Listening Thread"
    listen.start()
    print "Starting Listening Thread"
    listen.run()
    print "Creating Send/Receive Thread"
    sandr = threading.Thread(target=srcv(s, conn, data))
    print "Preparing Send/Receive Thread"
    sandr.start()
    print "Connections Now Acceptable"
    sandr.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(start_server())
```

Please let me know if my code seems clunky/disorganized, I am somewhat new to programming in general.

EDIT:

Another problem I encountered is that I cannot run both of the threads, as when one starts, the other can not be. Why is that, and how can I fix it?

Comment: You may want to post your coad.

Comment: @amitnair92 There, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use put the arguments in `args=` so that the function is not called before `listen.start()`:

```
listen = threading.Thread(target=listn, args=(s,conn,data))
```

Not

```
listen = threading.Thread(target=listn(s,conn,data))
```

Also you shouldn't call `.run()`, `.start()` does that internally on the newly started thread. The`run` method is there so that subclasses of Thread can override it.

Comment: This does work, but I have another problem: How do i go about starting the other thread, since there are two of them?

Comment: I dont know if notifications for comments on answers work, so here just in case.

Comment: The same way as the first thread. I only did one as the other is the same except that the `target=` is `srcv` rather than `listn`.